# PostgreSQL ascending maxes by date

Tags: sql, postgresql, design-patterns, postgresql-9.2

I would like to extract from a table of results over time a list of maximums at the time when values can fluctuate up or down. For example a cricket highscore database would have many results but I want to list off which batsman had the highest one-day score against the dates on which that record was achieved.

I haven't been able to find a pattern for this type of query although a CTE checking the previous row seems close. Can someone help with the pattern name or an example of an efficient way of achieving this query?

example data

```
Value | date
1| 1/1/1970
2| 2/1/1970
1| 3/1/1970
2| 4/1/1970
1| 5/1/1970
3| 6/1/1970
10| 22/1/1970
4 | 1/12/1970
7 | 22/5/1975
```

expected result

```
Value | date
1|  1/1/1970
2|  2/1/1970
3|  6/1/1970
10| 22/1/1970
```

I'm starting to think a self join would work fine.

Comment: Please add example data(sqlfiddle preffered) and example output.

Comment: So basically you need the min() date for each value?

Comment: No. If a value hasn't been used before that's entirely irrelevant. I want to know when a score is greater than all previous scores on the date of that score (value in example data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done by simply `LEFT JOIN`ing the row with all the previous one and checking if `max(value)` of those is smaller than in the current row (or `NULL` for the first row)

```
SELECT t1.value
       ,t1.date
FROM Table1 AS t1
  LEFT JOIN Table1 AS t2
    ON t1.date > t2.date
GROUP BY 
  t1.id
HAVING
  max(t2.value) IS NULL 
  OR max(t2.value) < t1.value
ORDER BY t1.date;
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3df14/2)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the data and results, you seem to want the *first* day that a particular value was hit.  You would do this using aggregation, but with the `min()` function:

```
select value, min(date) as date
from table t
group by value;
```

At the very least, this will give you the desired results in the question.

EDIT:

So you want the first date of a cumulative max.  You can get this too.

```
select cummax, min(date) as date
from (select date, max(value) over (order by date) as cummax
      from table t
     ) t
group by cummax;
```

Comment: Afraid not. Have added more data. Pick whatever sport you associate with. I'm after date ordered high score records.